# JAX-WS Duplicate complex type with different case in wsdl file

Tags: java, xml, web-services, soap, wsdl

**My problem is:**

while compiling WSDL file to generate java object using xjc  command, getting console error like ...

```
parsing a schema...
compiling a schema...
[ERROR] A class/interface with the same name "com.saico.ws.dto.PERSONinfodata" is already in use. Use a class customization to resolve this conflict.
  line 23 of file:/D:/WSDL/TESTService.wsdl

[ERROR] (Relevant to above error) another "Personinfodata" is generated from here.
  line 29 of file:/D:/WSDL/TESTService.wsdl

[ERROR] This error is caused because on Windows you cannot have both "Personinfodata.java" and "PERSONinfodata.java" in the same directory.
unknown location

Failed to produce code.
```

**COMMAND APPLIED:->**  D:\WSDL>xjc -wsdl -p com.saico.ws.dto MOCService.wsdl

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I am trying to resolve it since couple of days. Thanks in advance ..

I will attach WSDL file, if required .

Answer (score 0):

You have an entity with the same name, residing in namespaces with the same name (the same namespace?), in two different XML schemas. 
For instance, you have the Book entity/type in both the Contact.xsd and Opportunity.xsd schemas. 
The solution for this type of issue is to use the customization, see [Class Customization](http://jax-ws.java.net/nonav/2.2.7/docs/ch03.html#standard-customizations) section for details or [samples](https://svn.java.net/svn/jax-ws~sources/branches/jaxws22/jaxws-ri/samples/src/main/samples/external-customize/etc/custom-client.xml).